# Localisation resx not being picked up in .NET MAUI

Tags: resx, maui, .net-maui

I've started moving my native app into MAUI but are having issues with getting the translated resx values to get picked up.
Note! The default resx-translation values are used, so it's just the localized resx that isn't working.

- I've added two resx-files, AppRes.resx and AppRes.sv.resx
- I've set the applicable languages in `<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>` in the info.plist file (on both ios and maccatalyst)
- I've added the Microsoft.Extensions.Localization nuget package
- I've added `builder.Services.AddLocalization();` to the MauiProgram file
- I'm assigning the value in the xaml-file as `<Label Text="{x:Static res:AppRes.Account_SignInLabel} ...`

What am I missing? As stated above, I can see that the default AppRes.resx file is being used as changes to the value is displayed in my page, but it won't pick up the Swedish translation. Tried on both ios simulator and maccatalyst simulator (yes, the sim is displaying Swedish).

Side note! Not sure this is relevant but `string lang = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;` on the page in question will return null, where I perhaps expected "sv"?!

Comment: Anything helpful in [Localization in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/localization)? As a test, if you set `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ...;` to the desired culture, does it work?

Comment: I can set the culture manually/programatically as you suggest but it still just retrieves the default resource values, i.e. "en".

Comment: Set it in App.xaml.cs?  (or any time before calling page's constructor).

Comment: yes, just after InitializeComponent

Comment: IMHO, Statics are resolved during InitializeComponent. so must set culture *before* that. A typical place to set would be in App.xaml, *before* creating any page. (Though if TwoLetterIsoLanguageName is null, not sure how to find correct one.) As a test, you can put in page's constructor - but *before* InitializeComponent.

Comment: No change unfortunately. Even tried adding the System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE"); to the public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp() method. What's strage is that if i on a page hover System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture in debug I can see that the structure is populated with Swedish locale, but when trying to assign using var lang = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;, the lang variable is null?

Comment: Sounds like a Maui or .net 6 bug. I suggest making a simple **github public repo** that shows the problem. Post a new issue at [maui issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). Add the details you've given here, and link that issue and this SO question to each other.

Comment: Looked at a Maui Blazor example and maybe I'm missing something about the injection of the IStringLocalizer?